# How does IoC create instances for beans

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I learned that when IoC container initializes, it creates instances and injects the dependencies.

How does it create the objects? Is it creating them using the new operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the only way to instanciate an object, is to call a constructor.
You can call the constructor using the `new` operator or by reflection.

Spring use reflection to instanciate an object.

Answer (score 0):

1 Classes if they have a non-private constructor defined and same is declared in configuration metadata, are instantiated using reflection. [`getDeclaredConstructor()` of a class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html) [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29)

1. Some classes are instantiated using the static or non static factory methods if defined in the metadata.

Please read section 4.3.2 Instantiating beans from [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class)